# How to pack cache files?

Tags: smoke-simulation, blend-files, cache

Is it possible to pack the smoke cache files into the blend file, like can be done with images?
How can I do that? I only need the cache of one single frame.

Comment: related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/can-i-save-the-baking-cache

Comment: Yes but I want to store the cache inside the blend file... And not in an folder..

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible unfortunately. To make cache and .blend together I think the easiest way would be to archive them with compression tool

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out that the smoke-cache, (and other "cache bakes"), *are* actually stored in the .blend, if not set to bake externally. I tested this by baking a smoke sim, then stopping it at frame 40. I exited Blender, then loaded the file again. All the information for the smoke was still there.