# object separating itself during softbody simulation

Tags: soft-body

First time asker hope I'm doing this right!
I've made a jellyfish and wanted to try out softbody physics with it. Since it's a bit too much for my laptop to handle i put it inside a ball and linked the two with ctrl+j, making them the same object. I though since the ball was less complex it would be easier to calculate its collision with the plane, and it does bounces as I wish. Unfortunately the jellyfish gets out of the ball and splashes on the plane. (see gif attached) Is there a way to make the jellyfish stay inside the ball?
Thanks in advance !
[image: the ball slowly collides with the plane. as it does the jellyfish gets out of it and stays on the plane as the ball bounces up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a tricky problem.

The mesh geometry (length of the edges for instance) is of influence on the physics settings (like Edges Push and Pull values) and thus on how the object behaves during physics simulation. Because you have essentially two (very different) meshes in one object, they behave differently.

You could try to simply connect the to meshes in Edit Mode:
[image]

But the added edges will somewhat influence the shape of your meshes:
[image]

Also I don't think it will work for your jellyfish, since it is a more complicated mesh. I think if you want to control the behavior of both meshes, you'll have to make them two different objects, and sync their movement. I think I would animate the jellyfish manually without physics, to follow the movement of the ball.

(You might not need it, but just in case: If you were to do this, it might help to know about Cache setting to keep you simulation from changing for some reason. [Can I save the baking cache?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/can-i-save-the-baking-cache.))

Not great answer I think, but I hope it helps. : )